# iOS - Push notification with Layer.com

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, layer

I try to push notification with Layer API by:

```
let text = "Hello world" 
var error: NSError?

let part = LYRMessagePart(text: text) 
let message = layerClient.newMessageWithParts([part], options: [LYRMessageOptionsPushNotificationAlertKey : text], error: &error) 
self.layerConversation = getLayerConversation() 
self.layerConversation.sendMessage(message, error: &error)
```

Everything work well in the first time I logged in - there's a push and a message in layer log, but after that, when I try to push another notification, there's no push, just a message? How can I fix it?

Comment: solved it? I'm stuck too

Comment: Because I chose wrong provisioning, after I changed it and everything work well.
Check this link:
https://support.layer.com/hc/en-us/articles/204632870-How-do-I-troubleshoot-issues-with-Push-Notifications-on-iOS-